# I can't run a task while the thread is sleeping

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

In our system, I was tasked to create a page that will display our system's major threads in real time.

To recreate a major process, I was planning on creating a thread and let it sleep for at least 5 seconds. While the said thread is sleeping, I will get all of the active threads, see if the thread I created is there, and then store the thread information to my modelMap that will be passed on my JSP to display it.

When I tried to do it though, the test I managed to create waited for the Thread to finish sleeping first instead of what I wanted for it to act.

My Main Thread :

```java
        SampleThread1 sampleThread1 = new SampleThread1();
        sampleThread1.setName("SAMPLE THREAD 1");
        sampleThread1.run();

        initializeMajorProcess ();

        sampleThread1.interrupt();
```

SampleThread1 :

```java
    class SampleThread1 extends Thread {
        public void run () {
            try {
                System.out.println("-------- thread is starting");              
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                System.out.println("-------- thread is done");              
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println(this.getName() + "Interrupted");
            }
        }
    }
```

initializeMajorProcess :

```java
    private String initializeMajorProcess () {
        Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
        Set<Thread> nonDaemonThreads = new HashSet<Thread>();

        for (Thread thread : threadSet) {
            if (thread.isDaemon() == false && !thread.getName().startsWith("MyScheduler")) {
                System.out.println(thread.getId());
                System.out.println(thread.getName());
                System.out.println(thread.isAlive());
                nonDaemonThreads.add(thread);
            }
        }

        return "frps/DeveloperDashboard";
    }
```

I'm just a junior developer with one year work experience. It is my first time handling threads and my first time asking on StackOverflow so please don't be so rough on me :((

I would also want to ask how do I display the thread information real time? Do I have to use WebSocket or do I have to use AJAX?

Comment: Ajax should be suitable for this task.  Consider using Javascript `setInterval`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Thread.sleep(5000);` sleeps the main thread under execution i.e. your main class because you haven't triggered a thread rather just called the run method.

Hence, rather call `sampleThread1.start();` in place of `sampleThread1.run();`.

Comment: I did it but now it's finishing the initializeMajorProcess first before starting the thread. 

My console printed this :

1
main
true
-------- thread is starting
SAMPLE THREAD 1Interrupted

Comment: We can help is finding issues or programmatic concerns etc but debugging of your code must be done by you yourself:). That's how you learn

Comment: anyways `sampleThread1.interrupt();` code is causing thread to terminate. I don't want to disappoint you. But I highly recommend you practice more.